# How to include renderPrint() together with other rendering in one panel

Tags: r, shiny, flexdashboard

I have the following Shiny-Rmarkdown app:

````
---
title: "My First Shiny"
runtime: shiny
output: 
  flexdashboard::flex_dashboard:
    orientation: rows
    vertical_layout: scroll
---


```{r setup, include=FALSE}
library(flexdashboard)
library(tidyverse)
library(d3heatmap)
library(ggplot2)
```


Rows {data-height=800}
-----------------------------------------------------------------------

### Plot1

Here is the attempt


```{r}
# x <- datasets::iris[,-5] # [c(2:4,7),1:4]
checkboxInput("cluster", "Apply clustering")

renderD3heatmap(
  d3heatmap(mtcars, 
          dendrogram = if (input$cluster) "both" else "none",
          scale="none",
          xaxis_height = 170,
          yaxis_width = 170,
          height=200,
          cexRow = 1.0, 
          cexCol = 1.0,
          k_row = 6,
          k_col = 6
          )

)

renderPrint({tibble::as.tibble(mtcars)})

```

*** 

Some commentary about Frame 2.

### Plot2
````

It produces the following app:

[image]

Notice that although I have this line:

```
renderPrint({tibble::as.tibble(mtcars)})
```

It doesn't show at the bottom of `Plot1` panel. What's the right way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

`renderD3heatmap` does not have `outputArgs` that is used by `renderPlot` to pass `width` and `height` arguments to `plotOutput`, so I think you can not really do it that way.

Instead you might want to use `orientation: columns` and create 2 columns, which you then split:

````
---
title: "My First Shiny"
runtime: shiny
output: 
  flexdashboard::flex_dashboard:
    orientation: columns
    vertical_layout: scroll
---


```{r setup, include=FALSE}
library(flexdashboard)
library(tidyverse)
library(d3heatmap)
library(ggplot2)
```

Column 
-----------------------------------------------------------------------

### Plot1

Here is the attempt


```{r}
checkboxInput("cluster", "Apply clustering")
renderD3heatmap(
  d3heatmap(mtcars, 
          dendrogram = if (input$cluster) "both" else "none",
          scale="none",
          xaxis_height = 170,
          yaxis_width = 170,
          height=200,
          cexRow = 1.0, 
          cexCol = 1.0,
          k_row = 6,
          k_col = 6
          ))
```

### Data

```{r}
renderPrint({tibble::as_tibble(mtcars)})
```

*** 

Some commentary about Frame 2.

Column
-----------------------------------------------------------------------

### Plot2
````

[image]

Comment: But I want it to be in the same panel with `Plot1`. Not possible?

Comment: Neversaint, I believe your renderPrint() output is there, but that the renderD3heatmap() hogs the entire height of the column.  Not sure how to stack multiple render...()s in a single row.  Not helpful, I know.